# Inno setup - how to set installer "Run as non Admin"?

Tags: error-handling, inno-setup, privileges

I would like to run installer with no admin privileges.
But when i would like to run my created .exe file, this error message appears:

```
Unable to execute file in the temporary directory, Setup arborted.

 Error 1260: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system 
 administrator.
```

Is ist possible to fix this problem in the inno setup script?

Comment: We do not know what "group policy" blocked your installer. It's your group policy. This is probably not an Inno Setup question at all.

Comment: Ok, thats what i ve already thought. But thanks for the quick answer!